# Python ggplot style missing gridlines

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, ggplot2

I am using the ggplot style `plt.style.use('ggplot')` however all my graphs are missing the gridlines. I already put in `plt.grid()` whenever I plot a figure but it doesn't work.

Comment: Because the ggplot style already has the grid activated, calling `plt.grid()` will ***de***activate the grid. Make sure to call `plt.grid(True)` instead if you need it - it shouldn't be necessary at all.

Answer (score 1):

Answered by [ImportanceOfBeingErnest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124317/importanceofbeingernest) in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59740173/python-ggplot-style-missing-gridlines?answertab=oldest#comment105629128_59740173):

> Because the ggplot style already has the grid activated, calling `plt.grid()` will ***de***activate the grid. Make sure to call `plt.grid(True)` instead if you need it - it shouldn't be necessary at all.